# Why jade outputs code in one line in html file

Tags: pug, atom-editor

I'm using atom editor with jade to create code.Problem is that jade outputs whole code in only one line,in html file.Any way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what are you using to compile your jade.

But whatever you use there surely is a configuration to output the html "Pretty" or not. Yours is set to "false", which results in compressed HTML output.

As example if you are using the simple Node command 
(documentation: http://jade-lang.com/api/)

The needed exerpt:

> All API methods take the following set of options:
>
> {
>       pretty:boolean | string }
>
> Adds whitespace to the resulting html to make it easier for a human to
>   read using '  ' as indentation. If a string is specified, that will be
>   used as indentation instead (e.g. '\t').